# Why does the start button in the third frame of the main window not executing the counter functionality ?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

## Creating three "windows" that the user can navigate through using Back and Next - buttons.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
```

## Creating the counter

```
def a():    


    def counter_label(label):

        counter=0
        def count():

            global counter
            counter += 1
            label.config(text=str(counter))
            label.after(1000,count)
        count()
    label=tk.Label(third_frame,fg="red")
    label.grid(row=5,column=1)





def create_widgets_in_first_frame():
```

## Creating the label for the frame

```
    Label(first_frame,text="DATALOG CONTROLS AND SOLUTIONS PRIVATE LIMITED",padx=25,font=("arial",25,"bold"),bg="violet").grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=W)

    # Creating the button for the frame

    Button(first_frame,text="CONFIG",padx=25,pady=70,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",command = call_second_frame_on_top,width=10).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
    Button(first_frame,text="TEST",padx=25,pady=70,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",command=call_third_frame_on_top,width=10).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
    Button(first_frame,text="EXIT",padx=25,pady=70,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",command=root_window.destroy,width=10).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)

def create_widgets_in_second_frame():
```

## Creating the label for the frame

```
    Label(second_frame,text="SET CURRENT",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
    Label(second_frame,text="SET VOLTAGE",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
    Label(second_frame,text="SET TIME",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)


    def printVal():
```

## Creating the entry in second frame and print stored value in third frame

```
        string1 = entryval1.get()
        string2 = entryval2.get()
        string3 = entryval3.get()
        Label(third_frame,text=string1).grid(row=1,column=1)
        Label(third_frame,text=string2).grid(row=1,column=3)
        Label(third_frame,text=string3).grid(row=1,column=5)

    entryval1 = Entry(second_frame)
    entryval1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    entryval2 = Entry(second_frame)
    entryval2.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    entryval3 = Entry(second_frame)
    entryval3.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
```

## Creating the button for the frame

```
    Button(second_frame,text="SAVE",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",command=printVal,width=10).grid(row=5,column=1,sticky=W)
    Button(second_frame,text="BACK",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),command = call_first_frame_on_top,bg="red",width=10).grid(row=5,column=2,sticky=E)
    Button(second_frame,text="NEXT",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),command = call_third_frame_on_top,bg="red",width=10).grid(row=5,column=3,sticky=E)

def create_widgets_in_third_frame():
```

## Creating the label for the frame

```
    Label(third_frame,text="SET CURRENT",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
    Label(third_frame,text="SET VOLTAGE",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W)
    Label(third_frame,text="SET TIME",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=1,column=4,sticky=W)

    Label(third_frame,text="CURRENT:",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)
    Label(third_frame,text="VOLTAGE:",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W)
    Label(third_frame,text="TIME:",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=W)
```

## Creating the button for the frame

```
    Button(third_frame,text="START",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),command=a,bg="red",width=10).grid(row=6,column=2,sticky=E)
    Button(third_frame,text="STOP",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),bg="red",width=10).grid(row=6,column=3,sticky=E)
    Button(third_frame,text="BACK",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),command = call_second_frame_on_top,bg="red",width=10).grid(row=6,column=4,sticky=E)
    Button(third_frame,text="EXIT",padx=25,pady=50,font=("arial",20,"bold"),command = quit_program,bg="red",width=10).grid(row=6,column=5,sticky=E)
```

## Creating the entry for the frame

```
    e1=Entry(third_frame,width=20)
    e1.grid(row=3,column=1)
    e2=Entry(third_frame,width=20)
    e2.grid(row=4,column=1)


def call_first_frame_on_top():
```

## This function can be called only from the second window.

## Hide the second window and show the first window.

```
    second_frame.grid_forget()
    first_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)

def call_second_frame_on_top():
```

## This function can be called from the first and third windows.

## Hide the first and third windows and show the second window.

```
    first_frame.grid_forget()
    third_frame.grid_forget()
    second_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)

def call_third_frame_on_top():
```

## This function can only be called from the second window.

## Hide the second window and show the third window.

```
    second_frame.grid_forget()
    third_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)

def quit_program():
root_window.destroy()

 ###############################
 # Main program starts here :) #
 ###############################

# Creating the root GUI window.

root_window=Tk()
root_window.geometry("1500x1000+0+0")
```

## Define window size

```
window_width = 1500
window_heigth = 1000
```

## Creating frames inside the root window to hold other GUI elements. All frames must be created in the main program, otherwise they are not accessible in functions.

```
first_frame=Frame(root_window,bg="blue", width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
first_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)

second_frame=Frame(root_window,bg="blue", width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
second_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)

third_frame=Frame(root_window,bg="blue", width=window_width, height=window_heigth)
third_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)
```

## Creating all widgets to all frames

```
create_widgets_in_third_frame()
create_widgets_in_second_frame()
create_widgets_in_first_frame()
```

## Hiding all frames in reverse order, but leave first frame visible (unhidden).

```
third_frame.grid_forget()
second_frame.grid_forget()
```

## Changing the background color of main window

```
root_window.configure(background="blue")
```

## Start tkinter event - loop

```
root_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi Alok, welcome to SO. I don't know if anybody is going to install your whole project to help you. Consider building a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to help.

Comment: thank you..J.Chomel

Comment: Do you _really_ need all that code for such a simple problem? I doubt it. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience..actually it's the whole project on which I'm working..I've already posted shorter lines of codes  for the above problem..